# How to use a Spring @Value from properties to set an annotation attribute

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to set an attribute in an annotation, using Spring `@Value`, but I get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Value to String`. Here is what I tried:

```
@Table(name = "myTable", catalog = @Value("${database.myCatalog}") )
```

Is it possible? And if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are a little bit confused with how Spring uses that annotation.

As far as I know, the only way that annotation can only be set [at field or method/constructor parameters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html).

Also, for Spring to resolve it, the POJO must be a Spring managed bean. That means that it must be defined in the Spring (Web)ApplicationContext implementation to be resolved.

Your question seems like you are annotating a JPA Entity which is not a Spring bean but a Class to be used by the JPA implementation that you are using (e.g. Hibernate).

Comment: You're right, of course an entity is not a Spring Bean. In that annotation, other than a literal value, I saw I can use a static final field from another class. I could have that field set from a constructor when my container starts, but the final requirement can't be relaxed. So if I want to configure that value outside source code the only solution that I found is declare two persistence contexts.